# What is the "App Id" that the Apple developer connection site is asking me for?

Tags: ios

I just signed up to be an iPhone Developer.  What is the "App Id"?  Is it my company name?  Is it just my application name?  Apple isn't very clear on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't think Alex's answer is *quite* right.

`com.myname.MyCoolApplication` is the "Bundle ID search string", or "Bundle identifier", depending on which Apple documentation you consult.

Here are some Apple developer resources:

- [Technical Q&A QA1713: When should I use a wildcard App ID?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1713/_index.html)

To get the full "App ID", you want the Team ID (generated by Apple) plus your Bundle Identifier (created by the developer). E.g., from [Q&A QA1713](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1713/_index.html),

> Example App ID: `ABCDE12345.com.foocompany.appname`
>
> - `ABCDE12345` is the Bundle Seed ID (generated by Apple)
> - `com.foocompany.appname` is the App ID's Bundle Identifier and needs to be the same as your app’s Bundle Identifier

Comment: Ok, but where do we find all of this information exactly?

Comment: do you know why the IDs in the folder `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/` for iOS simulators are all numerical? Are they randomly generated numbers or are they the same on any device or sim?

Comment: @eLillie, when you register an app id on the [developer site](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle) it shows the generated team ID on the registration page.

Answer (score 10):

Its a namespace for your applications.  For example:

```
com.myname.MyCoolApplication
```

it uses a reverse domain name sort of format with the idea that only 1 person owns a domain at a time.  You can make an App ID that is a wildcard like:

```
com.myname.*
```

And now you can replace anything in the spot of the * creating a suite of applications.

An App ID is an identifier that uniquely identifies the app. it may be explicit or wild card. 
explicit means exactly one app. if we , rather , want to use the same app id for diffrent apps then use wildcard app id. Thanks

Comment: An _explicit_ App ID identifies _uniquely_ an app. A wildcard App ID identifies multiple apps, thus can't be "uniquely" identifying.